# How to use a form to update the models list in a view without refresh using javascript (coffeescript) in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

Fundamentally, I'm trying to combine a couple of default rails views into one and use javascript (actually coffeescript) to avoid having to do a page reload.  Basically I want to combine what comes in the standard generated new and index functions so that when a new object is created it updates the list without having a page refresh.

I imagine this is a common technique in many applications although I haven't found a tutorial on it.  I've tried stitching together a solution from help here at StackOverflow and elsewhere but haven't quite gotten it all to work.  I decided to created a simple rails project both because I need help figuring it out and so others can follow along without getting bogged down in things specific to my application.

Below is the code.  There's a lot but most of it is standard and generated by rails.  I created a rails project (rails 3.2) and generated scaffolding (model, controller, view) for a Book that has two strings, a title and an author.  I then further modified the code as below.

I made sure the `Gemfile` contains `jquery-rails`

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

....

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then I added a new route for the list action in `Routes.rb`

```
...
match 'books/list' => 'books#list'
resources :books
```

Following by adding the action to the controller `books_controller.rb`

```
...
def list
  @all_books = Book.all
  @book = Book.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.js { render 'new_book_row', :format => :html, :layout => false }
    format.json { render json: @book }
  end
end
```

I make sure to have both `@book` to hold the new book and `@all_books` to be used for the table listing all books.

The `format.js` line should render the new table row (file given below) as html (setting layout to false so it only renders the partial and not the application view wrappers).

We create the corresponding views and partials in `views/books/`

`list.html.erb` contains

```
<h1>List Books</h1>

<h3>Add Book</h3>
<%= render 'new_book_form' %>

<h3>My Books</h3>
<%= render 'book_list' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
```

I've split it into two partials although obviously the partials could be folded into the view above.

The `_new_book_form.html.erb` partial is as below

```
<%= form_for @book, :remote => true, :html => { 'data-type' => :html } do |f| %>
  <% if @book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </div>
  <div class="add-button" id='add-button'>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It's all standard generated code except the form_for call.  I set `:remote => true` as was described at http://tech.thereq.com/post/18910961502/rails-3-using-form-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs to make it an ajax call. I needed to set `'data-type' => :html` so the response came as html and not script.

The `_book_list.html.erb` partial is also all standard generated code

```
<table id='book-list'>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @all_books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.author %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and `_new_book_row.html.erb` is also straightforward

```
<tr>
  <td><%= new_book.title %></td>
  <td><%= new_book.author %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', new_book %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(new_book) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', new_book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

The magic is in `books.js.coffee`

```
# don't load javascript until the whole page is laid out
$(document).ready ->

  # To save the book without reloading the page
  $('#add-button').click ->
    $(this).parents("form").submit()


  $('form#new_book').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
    $('#book-list').append(data).show()
```

I found I needed to delay adding loading the javascript until after the page is loaded otherwise it wasn't finding the elements (no surprising when you think about it).

---

`/books/list` displays the page correctly and the button does create a new instance of the Book model with the form fields without rendering the default `/books/<id>` page.

However

1. It's not refreshing the table.
2. It seems to be creating two instances of the object.
3. It's not rendering the partial (I also tried is as a non partial without the leading underscore) and instead is returning the html for `/books/<id>` (but again doing it twice) as shown below.

Dynamicdisplay
    
        ...
        
        ...
    
    
    Reload the page to get source for: /assets/books.css?body=1
    
    
        ...
        
        ...
    
    
    
    Book was successfully created.

**Title:**
    The Old Man and the Sea

**Author:**
    Hemingway

[Edit](/books/14/edit)
    |
    [Back](/books)
    Dynamicdisplay
    
        ...
        
        ...
    
    
    
    Book was successfully created.

**Title:**
    The Old Man and the Sea

**Author:**
    Hemingway

[Edit](/books/15/edit)
    |
    [Back](/books)

I think I'm close, I just need to get the javascript to get the right partial and update the DOM in the right place.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

2: I think you are getting two books created because you are triggering a form submit in your CoffeeScript:

```
$('#add-button').click ->
  $(this).parents("form").submit()
```

and Rails is doing the same thing automatically for you (because you have set the remote property on the form Rails will inject the client-side script needed to post the form contents by Ajax). So there are two requests for each submit button click.

3: The form will post the request to the `create` action by default because you have passed a new object to `form_for` so the `list` action is never called by the Ajax request. The generated `create` action saves the new object and then redirects to the `show` action so that is why you see the html for /books/:id being returned. If you need to post the form to a different action then you can do so by specifying the `url` option to `form_for`. For example:

```
<%= form_for @book, :remote => true, :html => { 'data-type' => :html }, :url => { :action => :list } do |f| %>
```

1: This is probably related to 3. The Ajax request is not returning the table row that you expect. After you get 3 fixed you can start to diagnose the problem to see whether this event is getting called:

```
$('form#new_book').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  console.log xhr, data, status
  $('#book-list').append(data).show()
```

The Rails guides are normally a pretty good place to start for tutorials but the Ajax one is looking a little out of date. The Rails way of doing Ajax can be a bit confusing. Rails Ajax requests often render a js.erb template to return JavaScript (CoffeeScript works too) that gets run as soon as the response arrives at the browser. That way you don't have to worry about hooking into the jQuery Ajax events, so you might want to consider that approach. The Rails Tutorial has [an example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3aa_working_follow_button_with_ajax).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were right about the javascript submit. Adding `:url => { :action => :list }` prevents the creation of the new object. I'm guessing that because it redirects to list instead of create nothing actually gets created.  When I do `alert data` in the coffeescript function I do see the html for the show view.